# How to send particular coupon to new registered user in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

How to send coupon code to newly registered user in woocommerce?

Answer (score 3):

The Following code will help you to send a mail to the newly registered user in woocommerce.

```
add_action('woocommerce_created_customer','wdm_custom_new_user_action',10,3);

function wdm_custom_new_user_action($customer_id, $new_customer_data, $password_generated){
     $to= $new_customer_data['user_email'];
     $subject='Your free Coupon new registration';
     $message="Here is Your free coupon id : newBee45 ";
     $headers="Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
     $attachments="";
     wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments );
}
```

Add this function to your custom plugin or child theme to make sure it won't get deleted on theme/plugin update.

Have tested the same. Let me know if the same works for you.

Comment: Thank You very much for reply. But i want to send Coupon code with an email. so how can i fetch coupon code from database?

Comment: Hi WisdmLabs,
i have tried this email code but its not working.

Comment: Hav made changes in answer try it first
If that doesn't work let me know the following:
Is smtp mail configured on your site?
Do you get the default mails on new user registration?
Were have you added the code?

Comment: To check if this function runs properly on the hook do one thing just set an option field in this function so that will get to know if this function executes in your case or not.
For that just follow the steps:
1) update_option( 'wdm_coupon_sent', $message );
Add the above line as 1st line in the function.
2) Register a new user
3) Search for option 'wdm_coupon_sent' in your DB from backend and check whether its there or not.

Comment: Thanks...
oky. let me try